# Set pointer to the beginning and the end of the word

Tags: c, pointers

User inputs a word. Then my code finds a length of the word and after that compare letters of the word by setting a pointer to the beginning and the end of the word. It starts to increment "beginning pointer" and decrement "end pointer" and compare letters in the loop. My problem is that how to assign pointer to the letter in the beginning and in the end of the word??? I try to assign a pointer to the word. And after printf it gives me a number.....I think its an address of the word or smth..This is my code....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int count,i;
    char *beginner_pointer;
    char *ending_pointer;
    //printf("This program was called with \"%s\".\n",argv[0]);
    if (argc > 1){

        for (count=1; count<argc; count++){    
      //      printf("argv[%d]=%s\n", count, argv[count]);
            int length = strlen(argv[count]);
           beginner_pointer = argv[count];
            printf("%d\n", *beginner_pointer);
        }    

    }
    //int length = strlen(argv[1]);
    //printf("%d", length);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to test for palindromes? Why don't you say so?

Comment: Yup I am. Because before that test I need to put my pointer to the beginning and end of the word))

Answer (score 2):

```
beginner_pointer = argv[count];
ending_pointer = beginner_pointer + length - 1;
```

Comment: thanks..I tried it..But beginner_pointer gives me full  word, I need only first letter of that word.....

Comment: The first character is at the beginning of the word. `*beginner_pointer` is one letter.

Comment: You can't use string functions to get single characters, since they want null-terminated strings, and you don't have a null between each letter in the word.

Comment: Oh I see..Then how i can come up with first letter in the word then?

Comment: test this: `beginner_pointer[0]==ending_pointer[0]` or `*beginner_pointer == *ending_pointer`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   // required for strlen()

int main(void) {

    char *p1, *p2;    // declare two char pointer

    char *s = "EVITATIVE";  // this is our string

    int sl = strlen(s);   // returns the length of the string, requires string.h

    p1 = s;             // p1 points to the first letter of s
    p2 = s+sl-1;        // p2 points to the last letter of s, -1 because of \0

    printf("%c\n", *p1);   // prints the first letter

    printf("%c\n", *p2);   // prints the last letter

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks man....But look at my code please..It is almost the same...But printf gives me whole word not the first letter...Thats I cant figure out..

Comment: If I run your code (and change `%d` to `%c` in `printf`), it prints the first letter of the input string. Have you run my code?

Comment: one the left of every post you will find a panel to accept the answer or vote it up (helpful contribution) or down (not helpful contribution). http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote